# Entity Framework + PostgreSQL code-first

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework

First time here. I'm trying to integrate Entity Framework with PostgreSQL using Visual Studio 2017 Community:

From Nuget, I installed this packages:

- EntityFramework.6.1.3
- Npgsql.3.2.2
- EntityFramework6.Npgsql.3.1.1

My project is a Web API with .NET Framework 4.6.2 (not core)

My `web.config` looks like this

```xml
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="Npgsql"/>
        <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql" support="FF" description="Data Provider for PostgreSQL" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5D8B90D52F46FDA7"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionFactory, Npgsql"/>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="Npgsql" type="Npgsql.NpgsqlServices, EntityFramework6.Npgsql"/>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

But, in the Nuget Packet Manager's console, after issuing `Enable Migrations`, I get this error:

> Checking if the context targets an existing database...
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.
>
> in System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DataRow providerRow)
>   in System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
>   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key, Func`3 handleFailedLookup)
>
>   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
>
>   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetService>b__0(Tuple`2 k)
>   in System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
>   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CachingDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
>   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
>   in System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
>
>   in System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
>
>   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
>
>   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.RootDependencyResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key)
>
>   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetService>b__0(IDbDependencyResolver r)
>
>   in System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   in System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
>   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.ResolverChain.GetService(Type type, Object key)
>   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.CompositeResolver`2.GetService(Type type, Object key)
>
>   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DbDependencyResolverExtensions.GetService[T](IDbDependencyResolver resolver, Object key)
>
>   in System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateConnectionFromProviderName(String providerInvariantName)
>
>   in System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)
>
>   in System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)
>
>   in System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
>
>   in System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_Connection()
>
>   in System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_Connection()
>
>   in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config, DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Func`1 resolver)
>   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
>   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
>   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
>   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
>   in System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   in System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
>   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldInitialCreate(String language, String rootNamespace)
>   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   in System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
>
> Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Npgsql to the GAC with the Windows Installer. This can help a lot of the time.

[Download](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/releases)

Also, check the version number in the `DbProviderFactories` using:

```
typeof(Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory).AssemblyQualifiedName
```

And make sure they match.

Answer (score -2):

I had used this tutorial some time ago 
[Using Entity Framework 6 with PostgreSQL (archive.org)9889](https://web.archive.org/web/20141115210245/http://rob.conery.io/2014/02/05/using-entity-framework-6-with-postgresql/)

Comment: Please give the answer here because the URL may broken in future.

Comment: ;) The link is broken.